# Heroku Login Error from Command Line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-toolbelt

When I tried login to Heroku from the command line `heroku login` prompts the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'     
from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'   
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:131:in `setup'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu please try to execute command `sudo apt-get install openssl` and try again

Comment: I tried installing Openssl using apt and rvm.
Still prompts the following error.